# got an error message unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts in vb.net

Tags: mysql, windows, vb.net, phpmyadmin

i want to connect with mysql phpmyadmin database and get data in my application in vb.net but i can not connect.i got error message that unable to connect with specified host.
when i entered 10.1.1.53/phpmyadmin in my browser i am able to open my all database without any password or username but when i try to connect with my vb.net application by clicking button i got error message.
this is my code. please help me.

```
ImportsMySql.Data.MySqlClient

PublicClasslogin
Dim con AsMySqlConnection
Dim reader AsMySqlDataReader
Dim command AsMySqlCommand
DimmyconAsString = "server=10.1.1.53/phpmyadmin;database=dbtest"
PrivateSubbtnlogin_Click(sender AsObject, e AsEventArgs) Handlesbtnlogin.Click
login()
EndSub
PrivateSublogin()
con = NewMySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = mycon
Try
con.Open()
Catch ex As Exception

EndTry
EndSub

PrivateSubbtnexit_Click(sender AsObject, e AsEventArgs) Handlesbtnexit.Click
Me.Close()
EndSub

EndClass
```

Comment: can i see your login() function?

Comment: Private Sub login()
con = NewMySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = mycon
Try
con.Open()
Catch ex As Exception

EndTry
EndSub

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub login()

    Dim DatabaseName As String = "dbtest"
    Dim server As String = "10.1.1.53"
    Dim userName As String = "username"
    Dim password1 As String = "pass"

    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password1, DatabaseName)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        ' MsgBox("Connected")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'conn.Close()
End Sub
```

the one that u gave me is DimmyconAsString << is that typo?

Comment: please explain..i can't get it

Comment: `DimmyconAsString = "server=10.1.1.53/phpmyadmin;database=dbtest"` this is what you give at above..

Comment: my connection string including with server name and database name

Comment: Did you think DimmyconAsString is correct? I think its Dim mycon As String

Comment: i updated the code above.. give it a try. just edit databasename, server, username and password.. Please tidy up you code above.. Too much words is merging.. i not sure whether is correct or not

Comment: Try to echo it see its connected or no.. Please check the server, username and password of the server.. For the server u just need to put the ip address is enough.

Comment: its give error like this...system.null reference exception:-object reference not set to an instance of an object...

Comment: change the con the you declared to conn.. or u can change the conn in the login() into con.

Comment: Please update your current code. And please recheck the words ... because previously the one that you give is most of the keywords is merging and combined..